# Urdu Language showing question mark oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

I have report in which columns have multiple Languages English and Urdu. In database both Languages are showing in correct format. I tested in oracle forms and both Languages in correct format but In oracle reports only urdu Language showing Question Mark.

```
select * from nls_database_parameters where parameter='NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8

SELECT * from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter IN ( 'NLS_LANGUAGE', 'NLS_TERRITORY', 'NLS_CHARACTERSET');

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ ----------------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY                  AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8
```

Oralce database 11g and Forms & Reports

How to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: how about u OS? linux? windows? any other?

Comment: @Needle file  Linux 6.7

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is not enough that database displays it correctly - you have to use a **font** that is capable of displaying those characters. It has to be installed on IAS as well (not only on client computers).

Answer (score 0):

in linux 
set enveroment NLS_LANG before run u sofrware (Forms & Reports).

i don't know value for urdu.
for cyrilic like as `export NLS_LANG=RUSSIAN_CIS.AL32UTF8`

Comment: I tried with export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8. In HTML format report urdu Language show but did not showing in PDF Format

Comment: i don't know Oracle Forms & Reports. srr. try to set NLS_LANG for OS user who launches Oracle Forms & Reports in .bash_profile